# Why exports = module.exports = {}; ? Why not just module.exports?

Tags: node.js, express

My module.exports = foo is returning a blank object {}. Can anyone explain this?

Only if i use exports = module.exports = foo that my object isn't blank.

Comment: Post your module code. `module.exports = ???` is the right way.

Answer (score 4):

`module.exports` is the variable that matters when defining exports.  It's the actual object that will be returned from the `require('moduleName')` statement.

For convenience, node predefines `exports` as an alias essentiallly via:

```
var exports = module.exports;
```

That way you can then assign to either `module.exports` or just to `exports`.  So, you can do either of these and they create the same result because `module.exports === exports`:

```
module.exports.myFunc1 = function() {};
module.exports.myFunc2 = function() {};
```

or this:

```
exports.myFunc1 = function() {};
exports.myFunc2 = function() {};
```

But, when you redefine `module.exports` by assigning a new object to it, then `exports` is no longer the  same object as `module.exports`.

```
module.exports = {
    myFunc1: function() {},
    myFunc2: function() {}
};
```

Now, `exports !== module.exports` because you assigned a new object to `module.exports` and `exports` still points to the original `module.exports`.

So, to preserve the way it was originally (in case any other code in your module refers to `exports`, it is common to make sure that `exports` is again the same as `module.exports` with code like this:

```
module.exports = exports = {
    myFunc1: function() {},
    myFunc2: function() {}
};
```

If the code in your module never refers to `exports` itself, then you do not need to use it in any way because only `module.exports` actually matters to the outside world.

Comment: @geoyws - Though this is an old question/answer, if you're still around and this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer and also earn yourself a few reputation points.

Answer (score -1):

There is two ways to fullfill exports for your module. Choose whatever you like.

1) You can use add multiple properties to your module like that:

```
exports.foo = function () {};
exports.bar = function () {};
```

2) You can define single object like class, for example.

```
module.exports = Module;
function Module () {}
```

`exports` is just an alias for `module.exports`.

Use it when you want to return a object from your module, fullfilled with multiple properties.

Use `module.exports` when you want to return just a single value from your module.

If you define your module with `module.exports`, `export` itself becomes just a predefined variable, and you don't need to rewrite it.

All this you can find in docs 
http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_object